# Why can't we use dynamic methods instead for Generic(T) methods

Tags: c#, .net, function, generics, dynamic

I have Two functions defined as follows. Method 1 will return any type dynamically, method 2 will return generic types:

**Method 1**

```
public dynamic dynamicFun(int n)
        {
            switch (n)
            {
                case 0:
                    return 0;
                case 1:
                    return "N";
                case 2:
                    return 1.3;
                default:
                    return 'v';
            }
        }
```

**Method 2:**

```
  public static T genericFun<T>(int n)
        {
            switch (n)
            {
                case 0:
                    return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(0, Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)));
                case 1:
                    return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType("N", Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)));
                case 2:
                    return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(1.3, Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)));
                default:
                    return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType('V', Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)));
            }
        }
```

Both are doing the same functionality. The function call will be described in the image shown below:
[image]

Now my question is that ;

- What is the difference between these two methods?
- Where we can use dynamic methods and where we can use generics?
- is there any advantage for generic over dynamic?

Comment: `is there any advantage for generic over dynamic?` It gives you compilation check

Comment: dynamic is slower as it does runtime binding  every time.

Comment: There's a pretty simple acid test available.  If you use switch() or typeof() in a generic method then high odds that it shouldn't be generic.  The brevity of the dynamic method is another lead.

Comment: @HansPassant typeof() itself is fine. Think of caching in a dictionary.

Comment: @ neel : In this case dynamic method is faster that generic. i have checked with stop watch, the elapsed ticks for dynamic method is `613` where as generic is `4412`

Comment: yes. the advantage is that you can use `where` clause. [generic type constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)

Comment: @ m-kazem-akhgary : Gives me error `cannot convert type string to T`

Comment: @KhanhTO where would that check be? You can pass in any T and it can be wrong. No checking at all.

Comment: Your dynamicFun should return object, not dynamic. dynamicFun does not use any of the features of dynamic. Let the caller decide whether he wants to use dynamic at all or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why can't we use dynamic methods instead [of] Generic(T) methods?

It seems to me you can, proven by your examples and the runtime values show . But there's an inherent error in your thinking with the examples: you *know* what type is being returned in your generic method, so you're instantiating it that way. If I did `var genericCase1 = genericFun<int>(1)`, what would be returned? An exception would probably be thrown because "N" is not an integer.

### What is the difference between these two methods?

Dynamics are determined *at runtime* whereas generics are resolved *at compile time*.

### Where we can use dynamic methods and where we can use generics?

I would guess anywhere you could use a method. The reason you would use one over another is really based upon the situation you're in. If you do not know the exact Type that will be returned to you at the time of writing, then go the dynamic route. You can use this when you know your dealing with a few different base/super classes that have a particular method, and you want to hit that method, but you don't care which derived class is returned from the dynamic method.

Generics could be used to avoid writing a lot of overloads for the same functionality. If you know that you want to perform the same actions on many different things, then create a generic method, and pass the types you want to do stuff with during your writing. Using Type Constraints is really great too, because now you can limit what Types are able to call this generic method, and realize any issues at compile time.

### is there any advantage for generic over dynamic?

As others have said in the comments, there are time concerns, one method may take longer than another, but I suppose pieces of that would be determined by the methods implemented, and the amount of work the JIT vs compiler has to do.

Generics would also allow type safety and reduction of errors since they are resolved at compile time. Generics may also be easier to maintain as there is not as much "magic" going on.

You should probably use dynamics sparingly, because although they are powerful, used incorrectly could provide many sleepless nights debugging.

---

If I'm wrong on any of this, please someone correct me. As most of us out there, I am learning too, and would appreciate feedback on any issues with my current understanding.

Answer (score 0):

A big plus of generics are that you can specify the type of T. E.g. `void doSomething<T> () where T : abstractParentClass`